# Hide run/debug launch configuration in eclipse run/debug dialog programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, launch-configuration

How to hide a given launch configuration type in eclipse run/debug dialog?

As asked here in this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389403) hiding with activities is not working for me.
 Are there any other ways to hide a given launch configuration type in eclipse run/debug dialog?

Answer (score 0):

The Preferences has a configuration for hiding configuration types (in 'Run/Debug > Launching > Launch Configurations').

You could set these preference values, but this is an **internal** API so may change without notice.

The preference store is:

```java
IPreferenceStore store = DebugUIPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
```

Filtering by launch type is enabled with

```java
store.getBoolean(IInternalDebugUIConstants.PREF_FILTER_LAUNCH_TYPES)
```

and the comma separated list of types to be filtered out is in

```java
store.getString(IInternalDebugUIConstants.PREF_FILTER_TYPE_LIST)
```

As I said this is all an **internal** API.

Comment: Any other way?One disadvantage of this solution is I have to use internal API also it is user preference i.e user again may uncheck this boolean value manually, then a given launcher type will appear in the list. So it doesn’t serve my  need. Can we listen to any listeners on run/debug dialog and completely remove a given launcher type(By override any methods)?I think solution in plugin.xml(in org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes extension point) is not possible with core expressions, isn't it so?

Comment: As far as I can see in the source code this is the only way.